# VBA MS Access - Versao aplicação

Tags: vba, microsoft-access

Alguém sabe como mudar a versão do meu aplicativo access. Tipo, no C# um coloco o número da versão no arquivo assembly, e depois consigo pegar isso é colocar num label por exemplo. Como eu faço isso no VBA MS Access?

Answer (score 0):

Eu utilizo uma tabela com um campo versão no frontend.
Assim, quando faço nova compilação, tenho um verificador nos clientes que compara a sua versão com a versão do servidor e se a do servidor for maior faz a atualização automaticamente.